# CoreWindowDialog shows full screen and not as narrow banner

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to display a CoreWindowDialog to prompt my users when they delete a record.

This is my code:

```
CoreWindowDialog dialog = new CoreWindowDialog("Are you sure you wish to delete this record?");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Yes", Id = 0 });
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "No", Id = 0 });

IUICommand command = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

When I call the ShowAsync method the dialog shows but it's shown full screen with my title at the top and the Yes/No buttons at the bottom.

How can I show this as a banner like the MessageDialog? (i.e. full width of the screen but with the height adjusted to the size of it's contents which is 2 buttons and a textblock)

There doesn't seem to be any properties to adjust the height.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using XAML, .Net4.5 and I am writing a Windows store app for a Windows RT device.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something? This seems to work for me. I just have a simple Windows Store App with a blank page with a button. The button click handler calls your code above. My popup is only as tall as need be to fit the content (not full screen height, but full screen width).

Comment: It's full height for me.

Comment: I've never seen anyone using `CoreWindowDialog`. Why not just use `MessageDialog` instead?

Comment: @chue x - it seems to randomly show either centered or stretched vertically.

Comment: @FilipSkakun - wow, if I show the dialog enough times, it does seem to randomly show in full screen mode. +1 on your comment about using MessageDialog instead of `CoreWindowDialog`.

Comment: Thanks all. I've switched over to the MessageDialog now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing the same thing. First time it looks right, second time it's full screen.

Anyway, if you wanted to achieve the same thing with the MessageDialog here's the code:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(string.Empty, "Are you sure you wish to delete this record?");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Yes", Id = 0 });
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "No", Id = 0 });

IUICommand command = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

The first parameter is empty string because you don't want any message content in your case, just the title.